# Доступ к базе данных(серверной) с помощью Connection Strings

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, веб-программирование

Всем привет есть простенькая программа с подключением к БД

```
         `MicronConfig config = new MicronConfig()
        {
            DatabaseName = "microninventory",
            Host = "localhost",
            User = "root",
            Password = "",
            Port = "3306",
        };`
```

И в паре с ней xampp + phpmyadmin с залитой туда БД. Дошел до точки развития когда пора эту бд заливать на сервер, начал монотонно гуглить, в основном нашел что простые хостинги поступают так:

> Может ли провайдер отвергать запросы которые идут на прямую?
>   Если речь идёт о хостинг-провайдере, то может. Зачастую у хостинг-провайдеров закрыт прямой доступ "снаружи" к MySQL

Меня это не остановило, выкопал [документацию](https://docs.plesk.com/ru-RU/onyx/customer-guide/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA.74201/) где это вполне возможно НО

> ...это адрес сервера баз данных. Если имя сервера указано как ‘localhost’, обратитесь к хостинг-провайдеру, чтобы узнать свой адрес сервера баз данных.

Вот уже часов шесть тыкаюсь по хостингам, везде одно и тоже... localhost, ни малейшего намека на полноценный адрес бд... написал заявки в службу поддержки... режим хатико on

Еще знаю что можно бэкенд написать на сервере (REST к примеру) но это не в моем случае, у меня он вшит в саму програму, собственно в этом вся ее суть...

Так же находил что то о выделенных серверах... попылася копать эту нишу но мне стало страшно... (*в теории если обьясните как на VPS установить MySQL, получить конфиг и дать доступ к удаленному подключению... буду премного благодарен за пинок в эту сторону, но согласитесь орендовать VPS ради одной БД...)

Еще пару вопросов в копилку:
-как правильно гуглить что бы найти сервера с уже нужными конфигами? (как вот открытый адрес БД, удаленное подключение) мне высвечивает 1) как подлючить бд локалхостом))) 2)тех поддержка бд, удаленный доступ к обслуживанию...
-поделитесь мануалами по VPS (я больше вариантов не вижу, буду арендовать супер компьютер для 1мб БД)
-поделитесь серверами (желательно с trial) где возможно разрешен доступ...

Comment: Перечитайте свой вопрос. Толи у вас пхп, толи у вас c#, то ли вам хостинг для сайта нужен, толи только для базы (А пхп вы где хостить будете?) Причем тут вообще c#? Вам c# хостить не надо? Ваш вопрос ничего не говорит о вашей задаче, а не зная вашу задачу никак не понять вашу проблему.

Comment: Запрет доступа к БД снаружи делают по причине безопасности. У вас же прописано `Host = "localhost"`, так в чем проблема?

Comment: "простенькая программа с подключением к БД, Дошел до точки развития когда пора эту бд заливать на сервер" мне нужно просто залить БД на сервер и подключится к ней через Connection Strings, извините но даже в названии это указано, не понимаю что не понятного, "Еще знаю что можно бэкенд написать на сервере" - тут я предельно ясно выразился как о C#  так и о всех языках программирования

Comment: Bulson, мне нужно такое: "Server: 10.58.103.102:3306”. In this example, ‘10.58.103.102’ is the database server address", у меня есть сотня .exe и каждая из них из любой точки мира должна получить доступ к БД на одном сервере, и я не думаю что это выйдет сделать через localhost XD

Comment: А потом какой-нибудь человек взял и подключился к вашей БД. В лучшем случае он просто завладел всеми данными. А в худшем еще и всем сервером, на котором могут работать другие приложения и другие БД. Поэтому никто из хостеров не открывает доступ к БД напрямую и обычно рядом с БД хостится само приложение на этом же сервере. Если же у вас декстоп приложение, то на сервере хостится какое-нибудь приложение с API для работы с ним, а оно уже лезет в БД. Ну или вы арендуете VPS и делаете на нем всё сами на свой страх и риск.

Comment: Ну или второй вариант, купить у провайдера белый IP адрес и использовать свой домашний компьютер.

Comment: это обычная програма по шаблону - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNTQy48Pafc  по поводу безопасности есть способы как защитить подключение и тд.. не волнуйтесь, но мне пофиг на защиту, мне нужно Просто подключить exe к БД

Comment: Вопрос не в том, пофигу это вам или нет, вопрос пофигу ли это хостеру, когда на одной СУБД располагается сразу несколько баз данных. И как правило хостеру не пофигу ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Не, ну может где-то и есть хостеры с такой услугой, но найти их будет сложно.

Comment: Я не думаю что если бы была дыра в безопасности то вообще оставили бы такой способ подключения, и не думаю что разработчики серверной части софта настолько глупые еще и написать как это делать в офф документацию для нескольких сотен хостов

Comment: ну не знаете и ладно, хватит воды, Прошу знающих ответить на конкретный вопрос как создать среду обитания My sql на VPS и открыть порты/дать разрешения на доступ к ней через адрес или кинуть гайды по этому всему

Comment: В VPS можете считать, что у будет обычный компьютер с Linux, на который можно удаленно подключиться. Ищете дешевый VPS сервер рублей за 150, в опциях указываете предустановленное ПО в виде LAMP сервера (или смотрите, как установить на Linux субд MySQL в пару строчек). Указывает в конфигах MySQL вместо 127.0.0.1 адрес 0.0.0.0, рестарт и должно заработать. Ну может еще firewall придется подправить: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-connect-mysql-database-in-my-vps.

Comment: Alex Krass прошу ваш последний пост отправить как ответ, все заработало!!! Первый раз сел за линукс, мне это даже понравилось, спасибо за подробную инструкцию!!

Comment: Ну с Linux работать не сложно до тех пор, пока не начинают появляться непонятные ошибки, вот тогда придется долго гуглить и страдать. Оформил последний комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хостинг провайдеры часто не предоставляют доступ к существующей базе данных из соображений безопасности и просто перестраховываются. Поэтому лучше рассмотреть вариант с дешевым VPS сервером.

У хостеров часто есть услуга предустановленного ПО, поэтому следует выбрать VPS с предустановленным LAMP сервером (Apache + MySQL + PHP). Тогда MySQL уже будет установлен на сервере. В противном случае MySQL надо будет установить в ручную в зависимости от дистрибутива Linux через команду `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` или `yum install mysql-server`.

Дальше в конфигурационном файле /etc/mysql/my.cnf (/etc/my.cnf) надо заменить адрес возможных подключений с локального 127.0.0.1 на любой 0.0.0.0.

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

И перезапустить сам сервер из терминала:

```
$> service mysql restart
```

После этого всё должно заработать.

---

Возможно придется еще настроить firewall:

```
Ubuntu: $> ufw allow from any to any port 3306
CentOS 6.x: $> iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT; service iptables save
CentOS 7: $> firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp --permanent; firewall-cmd --reload
```

P.S. Информация взята отсюда [how can connect mysql database in my vps?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-connect-mysql-database-in-my-vps)

Comment: Не а. Этого не достаточно. В настройках MySQL по-умолчанию запрещен пользователю `root` доступ с адресов кроме `localhost`. Так что придется еще создать пользователя, дать ему права на доступ к БД и адресов извне.

Comment: CREATE USER 'Noob'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'qwerty';
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'Noob'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
*это провереный рабочий вариант